# ui-icon buttons with no text don't show in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery-UI in my app. I'm using the ui-icon buttons as links to actions that apply to items shown in rows in a table. They work fine in all the browsers but IE 7.

See this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/CsNJa/

It works in IE 8 but not 7

Comment: Seeing as this example is basically pure jQuery UI and it doesn't work, it probably won't ever work how it works in newer browsers(or at all), sorry to say.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer. Is there a page where to find JQuery UI supported browsers?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/home At the end of the "Rich effects and UI widgets" paragraph. It say's IE6+ plus but I think the buttons are relatively knew so who knows.

Comment: I found a work around for my issue. It looks more of a hack than a solution to something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to perform the following changes to the elements.

```
        if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 7) {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-button");
            $(this).css("float", "left");
            $(this).css("margin-left", "3px");
        }
```

The margin is not really necessary. I just happen to have several buttons in a row.